# VS2022 Запретить автоматическое дополнение фигурных скобок

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть, к примеру, такой код:

```
if (st.Contains("author"))
```

При переходе на новую строку сочетанием клавиш `shift+enter` всегда выставляются скобки:

```
if (st.Contains("author"))
{

}
```

Как убрать такое поведение? Снимал все галочки в разделе Форматирование, но ничего не помогло.

Comment: А что у вас за редактор кода?

Comment: А вообще всегда ставьте фигурные скобки. https://habr.com/ru/articles/213525/

Comment: Редактор кода visual studio, я просто хочу после if поставить continue;

Comment: `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` (слева) -> `C#` -> `Code Style` -> `New Lines`. Возможно где-то там. Но это не точно, но я почти уверен, что это можно сделать во вкладке `Text Editor`. Если у вас русифицированная вижла, то крайне рекомендую сменить на английский, т.к некоторого функционала может просто не быть (например в `Team Explorer` при разрешении конфликтов отсутствуют некоторые кнопочки)

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` - без скобок, `Shift+Enter` - со скобками

Comment: А просто `Enter` перенесет и тоже будет без скобок

Comment: Aarnihauta, для этого сперва курсор строки нужно переместить в конец строки, много лишних действий.)

Comment: EvgeniyZ, да это работает.